# Need a suggestion for counting a number vertically in a node created by TikZ

Tags: latex, tikz

The goal is to create a node with a label in it. A label must count vertically from column 1, then proceed into another column. After doing some research with the "foreach" statement, I achieved this result by using this code.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{d}=[draw,circle,minimum size=10mm]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}
\foreach \y in {-1,...,-5}{
    \node[d] at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {};
    }
\foreach \x in {1}
\foreach \y in {-1,...,-5}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{-\y+\x-1}
    \node at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};
    }
\foreach \x in {2}
\foreach \y in {-1,...,-5}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{-\y+\x+3}
    \node at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};
    }
\foreach \x in {3}
\foreach \y in {-1,...,-5}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{-\y+\x+7}
    \node at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) {\label};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a simpler or more efficient way to achieve the same result? Any advice is welcome, and I am grateful for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about "simpler" but the code can definitely be more "parametric", hence easier to alter. You can use `evaluate` inside `\foreach` loops as well as macros, such as `\pgfmathsetmacro{<name>}{<value>}`. Also, the style `d` can be parameterised inlcuding the default value

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  d/.style = {draw,circle,minimum size=#1},   % d is parametrised with
  d/.default = 10mm,                          % the default value of 10 mm
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{1.25}     % parameters for the grid
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxcols}{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxrows}{5}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,\maxcols} {
    \foreach \i [
      evaluate=\n using {int(\i+\maxrows*(\j-1))},
      evaluate=\y using {\scale*(\maxcols-\i-1)},
      evaluate=\x using {\scale*(\j-1)},
    ] in {1,...,\maxrows} {
    \node[d=12mm] at (\x, \y) {\n};}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```